# regular expression for validating password field

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a learner in java script currently I am going through the regular expression for validating the password field, I want my password field to contain characters and only one number in any place of the string,

I tried the following regular expression it checks for at-least one number and one character in the string

```
^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$
```

Can anyone help me!

Comment: Do you want _only_ one number, or _at least_ one number?

Comment: I want only one number, that can be present at any place in the string

Comment: try `^(?=\D*\d\D*$)[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$`

Comment: `^(?=\D*\d\D*$)[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$`

Comment: (?=\D*\d\D*$) can u explain me what this actually does? I cant understand it.

Comment: This is a check at the start of the string making sure there is zero or more nondigits followed by a digit and zero or more nondigits up to the end of string.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is adding a lookahead at the start:

```
^(?=\D*\d\D*$)[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$
```

The lookahead makes sure there is zero or more nondigits followed by a digit and zero or more nondigits up to the end of string.

Comment: This regex allows a string that has at least one character. If you need to accept strings of 0 length, please drop a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this RE

**(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,15})$**

Comment: It doesn't satisfy my condition, It allows false inputs also.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler expression would be

```
^\D*\d\D*$
```

where the meaning is

- Zero or more non-numbers
- A number
- Zero or more non-numbers

If you want at least another character...

```
^(\D+\d\D*)|(\D*\d\D+)$
```

where the two provided alternatives require either before or after at least one non-digit.